# Combined constants in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two constants defined in XAML and I would like to define the third based on that two:

```
<UserControl ... xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <clr:Int32 x:Key="Constant1">1</clr:Int32>
        <clr:Int32 x:Key="Constant2">2</clr:Int32>

        <!-- Is it possible to achieve something like this? -->
        <clr:Int32 x:Key="Constant3">{StaticResource Constant1} + {StaticResource Constant2}</clr:Int32>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to keep it as a resource? Resources usually keep visual styles, like css is to html. If it's just data, why won't you keep it in the code? Also, resources aren't constant.

Comment: I could use code behind in order to achieve this, but I wonder if there is possibility to keep that in XAML. These values are intended to be used in view context like Grid.Column etc. And seeing that XAML is used to describe view, I decided to keep view-intended constants in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not as you want to do it.
One solution I can think of is a custom MarkupExtension like this:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(int))]
public class IntCalculator:MarkupExtension
{
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }

    public List<string> ResourceNames { get; set; } 

    public IntCalculator()
    {
        Values = new List<int>();
        ResourceNames = new List<string>();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var root = (IRootObjectProvider)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider));
        var rootObject = root.RootObject as FrameworkElement;
        int calcVal = 0;
        if (rootObject != null)
        {
            foreach (var resourceName in ResourceNames)
            {
                var resource = rootObject.FindResource(resourceName);
                if (resource != null && resource is int)
                {
                    calcVal += System.Convert.ToInt32(resource);
                }
            }
        }


        foreach (var value in Values)
        {
            calcVal += value;
        }
        return calcVal;
    }
}
```

With this Extension you can add int resources or int values.
This is how to use it:

- in your resources:

  ```
  <local:IntCalculator x:Key="CalcVal">
      <local:IntCalculator.ResourceNames>
          <clr:String>Constant1</clr:String>
          <clr:String>Constant2</clr:String>
      </local:IntCalculator.ResourceNames>
  </local:IntCalculator>
  ```
- to display the value:

  ```
  <Label Content="{StaticResource CalcVal}"/>
  ```